# How to parse a JSON string into a StructType with a specific schema in Pandas and send to a BigQuery table with Record type

Tags: json, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a pandas dataframe with one column being a Json object. I want to send the dateframe to a BigQuery table and map the json object to a column with a record type. But it is mapped to a column with a string type instead. In the Azure Databricks notebook, I was able do this by using from_json with my own defined schema. For example

```
df = df.withColumn("value", from_json(col("nestedJson"), jsonSchema))
```

But I am using Jupyter notebook in GCP and there is no from_json method there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me

Let's define a dummy dataframe with two columns (**id** and **nestedJson**)

```py
import pandas as pd
    
d = {'id': [1,2,3], 'nestedJson': [{'k1':1, 'k2':2}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4}, {'k1':5, 'k2':6}]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

So df looks like this

|  | id | nestedJson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | `{'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}` |
| 1 | 2 | `{'k1': 3, 'k2': 4}` |
| 2 | 3 | `{'k1': 5, 'k2': 6}` |

Now we create a bigquery Client, set the configuration for the load job (with schema autodetection) and load the data from a dataframe according to the BQ documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe)

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_id = 'my_dataset.my_project.my_table' # Change this for your destination 

client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

Finally you can check the job's result

```py
table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema)
    )
)
```

Which should print

> Loaded 3 rows and 2 columns

Your BQ table should look like this

Schema

| Field name | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | INTEGER | NULLABLE |
| nestedJson | RECORD | NULLABLE |
| nestedJson.k1 | INTEGER | NULLABLE |
| nestedJson.k2 | INTEGER | NULLABLE |

Preview

| Row | id | nestedJson.k1 | nestedJson.k2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 |

Finally it's worth noting that while using schema autodetection works fine, if you try to explicitly set the schema, you'll probably run into this issue
https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/19

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I got following warning: UserWarning: Pyarrow could not determine the type of columns: tokens. ", ".join(field.name for field in unknown_type_fields) I didn't get this warning with the example above, maybe because the nestedJson is still a little bit simple. My real case is very complex nested Json object, it is a result from a nlp rest api.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the response you get looks like?

Comment: For example, if I pass a sentence to the rest api, Sex: Female\n, {'documents': [{'id': '1', 'entities': [{'id': '0', 'offset': 5, 'length': 6, 'text': 'Female', 'category': 'Gender', 'confidenceScore': 1.0, 'isNegated': False, 'links': [{'dataSource': 'SNOMEDCT_US', 'id': '224526002'}]}]}], 'errors': [], 'modelVersion': '2020-09-03'}

Comment: It still works fine when I try a similar schema like this (you can replace `d` in the above example with this):
```python
d = {'id': [1], 'nestedJson' : [{'Sex': 'Female\n', 'documents': [{'id': '1', 'entities': [{'id': '0', 'offset': 5, 'length': 6, 'text': 'Female', 'category': 'Gender', 'confidenceScore': 1.0, 'isNegated': False, 'links': [{'dataSource': 'SNOMEDCT_US', 'id': '224526002'}]}]}], 'errors': [], 'modelVersion': '2020-09-03'}]}
```